# aws fargate lanuch type taking nearly 3 mins to start

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-fargate, aws-step-functions

I have a Docker image stored in Amazon ECR, which is about 3GB in size. Currently, when I trigger an AWS Fargate task using AWS Step Functions, it takes approximately 3 minutes for the container to start. I am looking for ways to reduce this startup time to under a minute.

Here are the relevant details:

1. Docker Image Size: 3GB (stored in ECR)
2. Launch Type: AWS Fargate
3. Startup Time: ~3 minutes
4. cpu=4gb, memory=8gb

my task definition is

```
    "run task": {
    "Type": "Task",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::ecs:runTask.sync",
    "InputPath": "$",
    "ResultPath": "$.input",
    "Parameters": {
      "LaunchType": "FARGATE",
      "Cluster": "${cluster_name}",
      "TaskDefinition": "taskdefinition",
      "NetworkConfiguration": {
        "AwsvpcConfiguration": {
          "Subnets": [
            "${private_subnet_id_2}",
            "${private_subnet_id_1}"
          ],
          "SecurityGroups": [
            "${aws_security_group}"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "END": true
  }
```

My questions are:

1. Are there best practices for optimizing the startup time of large Docker images in AWS Fargate?
2. Can specific settings in my task definition influence the startup time?
3. Is there a recommended way to streamline the image to reduce its size without compromising the necessary functionalities?

Any insights or suggestions to improve the startup time would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 3GB is a fairly huge image. Fargate is going to take several minutes to download, decompress, and create a container from that image. In my experience with Fargate, 3 minutes for a 3GB image is actually pretty good. Look into using a smaller base image (like Apline) and also look into doing multi-stage docker builds to reduce the final image size.

Comment: I reduced it to 3GB from 5 GB using a multi-stage build. is there any other method I can use to load the container quickly?

Comment: You can look into doing this: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/under-the-hood-lazy-loading-container-images-with-seekable-oci-and-aws-fargate/

Comment: thanks. Can I use EC2 instead of Fargate? can we preload container images in EC2 instance?

Comment: Yes EC2 would allow you to cache the image. As explained in the documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/bestpracticesguide/pull-behavior.html

Comment: @MarkB thanks for the suggestion. it's worked as expected. it's reduced time from 3 minutes to a few seconds.